# firebase authentication google sign

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication google sign in .APK works fine but showing error with status code 10: developer error in app bundle. Means when I am generating app bundle and test with firebase. It is showing this error.

I try to change the firebase and connect with other account of firebase